# "Could it be" or "could it have been" when asking about the reason someone did something or something happened in the past?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

Do I have to use the question *could it be* or *could it have been* when asking about the reason someone did something or something happened. For example:

> I can't believe Kate got the job. **Could it be** because she was lucky?
>
> I can't believe Kate got the job. **Could it have been** because she was lucky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those work. Their meaning is not all that different in practice. The second is more ponderous and probably less in use than the first.

You certainly don't *have* to use either of those (in answer to your question 'do I have to...?').

It's English: there's always another way to say/write things, some better than others. Substituting only for the second sentence:
 - 'Was she lucky or what?' (implies that you are fairly sure she was lucky).
 - 'Might luck be the reason?'
 - 'Could it be luck?'
 - 'To what might we attribute this? Luck?' (also a bit ponderous)
 - 'Dare I suggest luck as her secret helper?'

I'm not suggesting that any of these are better, or worse, but they are alternatives. Doubtless there are many more.